# Is it possible to upload SVG files to Media Manager?

Tags: web8, media-manager, image

I'm unable to upload an SVG as an asset - it seems like Media Manager doesn't support/recognise the SVG files. Is there a way to achieve this?

**Edit**

I've also tried uploading it as a multimedia component in Tridion, and pasting its source code into a rich text field - neither of which worked. Is there any way of using SVG within a Tridion website, or should I give up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.. only jpg/gif/png/tif/bmp, as per documentation link below
https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDLMediaManager212-v5/GUID-CF1C8C0E-41BF-4A8C-B185-3196DDA2B06C

Answer (score 4):

Replying to your edited question. SVGs are not supported by Media Manger, but that doesn't stop you from using them on your website.

You should be able to add them as multimedia Components into Tridion. You will have to add the extension/MIME type. See [Adding Multimedia Types](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-C171DEE7-0F1F-45EF-ACD6-7A9C5498925C).

Answer (score 3):

Media Manager can store *files* , in addition to images and videos. It might be tempting to try and consider SVG a "file" rather than an image.

Unfortunately, [even as a file, SVG is not supported](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDLMediaManager212-v5/GUID-CF1C8C0E-41BF-4A8C-B185-3196DDA2B06C#docid=GUID-7CB73DFD-ACAC-4E70-AA01-01FC27C17400&filename=GUID-FA766584-F5C3-4A57-96CF-A7E4CE46C6DD.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-7CB73DFD-ACAC-4E70-AA01-01FC27C17400)

[image: Media Manager Upload screen]

Media manager won't support SVG no matter how you try to upload it.